# cat emulator in Haskell

Tags: haskell

So I'm attempting to make a program that reads from a handle and writes to stdOut, like so:

```
import IO
import System

cat w   =   do  
            fromHandle  <- getAndOpenFile w ReadMode
            contents    <- hGetContents fromHandle
            putStr contents
            putStr "Done."

getAndOpenFile  :: String -> IOMode -> IO Handle

getAndOpenFile name mode =
      do
      catch (openFile name mode)
        (\_ -> do   
                putStrLn ("Cannot open "++ name ++"\n")
                return())
```

I'm fairly new to Hs and it seems like this should be far more simple than I'm making it for myself. Any suggestions to helping me move further?

the usage would be ./cat "foo.txt" and would print the text in the foo.txt file to stdOut.

Comment: Best question title ever. ・ω・

Comment: http://donsbot.wordpress.com/2006/12/18/programming-haskell-argument-handling-and-a-complete-cat/

Comment: See also: [Lambdacats](http://spl.smugmug.com/Humor/Lambdacats/13227630_eKt46#960526154_fqpKB).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is the below function which does what you want.

```
readFile :: FilePath -> IO String
```

use this with putStr to print the IO String

Comment: This works, but only in GHCI. If I attempt to compile it using ghc --make cat.hs, I get an error "The function 'main' is not defined in module 'Main'"

Comment: You need main function when you compile the code. The code you have pasted doesn't have main function which will actually execute the cat function. Also in main function you will need to get filename from arguments to the program as cat takes filename as argument